# How to manage angular layouts dynamic

Tags: angular, layout

In my `app.components.html`

```html
<div class="layout">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <!-- Page Container START -->
  <div class="page-container">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
  <!-- Page Container END -->
</div>
```

When I create a route it will get header and footer but some route like Login Page I don't need header and footer.

How can I show only `login.components.html` when browser URL `localhost:4000/login` and don't get header and footer?

Comment: all page i need header sidebar and footer only login i need full page without header sidebar and footer

Comment: Simply user ngIf with login and without login.

Answer (score 0):

You should create multiple router outlets with names.

```
 <div class="layout">
   <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
     <!-- Page Container START -->
   <div class="page-container">
      <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
   </div>
<!-- Page Container END -->
```

And then manage your routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        component: HeaderComponent,
        outlet:'header'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: FooterComponent,
        outlet:'footer'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```